# Angular Unable to Display Image from OMDBAPI

Tags: json, angularjs

I am learning AngularJS. In my application, I want to display movie posters that get from  `http://www.omdbapi.com`.

**HTML**

```
<div ng-app="moviesBrowserApp">
        <div ng-controller="moviesCtrl">
            <strong>{{movie.Title}}</strong>
            <div><img alt="{{movie.Title}}" ng-src="movie.Poster" /></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**Javascript**

```
var moviesApp = angular.module('moviesBrowserApp', []);
moviesApp.controller('moviesCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {
    $http.get('http://www.omdbapi.com/?i=tt0112462&plot=short&r=json').success(function (data) {
        $scope.movie = data;
    });
});
```

The problem is that the image is unable to display using the url from the json result. When I inspect the traffic I see the 403 status of each image but If those images are directly viewed via browser, then they display properly after page reload. Seems like it can only retrieve images from the browser's cache. Is it permission restriction from `omdbapi.com` or what? Is there a way to fix this issue?

Comment: It's http://www.omdbapi.com permission restriction ("You don't have permission to access #imageUrl on this server")

Comment: How does your JSON object look?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming movie.Poster has a valid image url on return - use [ng-src](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSrc):

```
<img alt="{{movie.Title}}" ng-src="movie.Poster" />
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Ben Diamant. I've already tried with ng-src. It still doesn't work.

Comment: can you console.log(data) in the success block and show the output? @sovantha

Answer (score 1):

If your JSON object looks like this:

```
{
    "Title": "Your Title",
    "Poster": "http://www.omdbapi.com/src/poster.jpg" 
}
```

you have to bind in HTML like this:

```
<img ng-src="{{movie.Poster}}" alt="{{movie.Title}}">
```

A very good post I have read [here](http://www.jptacek.com/2014/01/angularjs-lou-reed/), I had problem with broken image URL and this post helped me. 
Hope it will also be helpfull for you.

Comment: Here is my JSON object. {"Title": "Batman Forever", "Poster": "Poster":"http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BMjAwOTEyNjg0M15BMl5BanBnXkFtZTYwODQyMTI5._V1_SX300.jpg"}

Comment: You can't use the POSTER Api, you don't have permission for that, this is the only way to display the image via it's URL...

Answer (score 0):

I left this project for a while then I come back to play with it and it works as expected now. The `omdbapi.com` has enabled the permission, so I don't get 403 any more.